# While loop strangely breaking after user decided to filter data once again

Tags: python, while-loop

Cases:

1. When user doesn't enter value, print('empty field')
2. When user enters value, return that value and assign it to country variable in filter_by_country function.
3. When country variable has a value check if it exists in filtered_runners list.
4. When runner exists, return that runner as a list of runners.
5. When runner does not exists, ask user if he wants to continue or exit the program.

When I enter value, the value does not exists in list and I want to continue - program runs validate function once again but when I enter value it strangely break the program. What I did wrong? Thanks for feedback.

```
def filter_by_country(all_runners: list):
        country = validate()
        if country:
            filtered_runners = [runner for runner in all_runners if runner.country == country]
            if not filtered_runners:
                choice = ""
                while choice == "":
                    choice = input('No runner found. Continue? [y/n]').lower()
                    if choice == "y":
                        country = validate()
                        break
                    if choice == "n":
                        print('See you soon')
                        break
                    if choice == "":
                        print('No value in input')
                        continue
            else:
                print(filtered_runners)
    
    def validate(country: str = ""):
        while country == "":
            country = input('Enter some value: ')
            if country != "":
                print(country)
                return country
            else:
                print('Empty field')
```